# Understanding polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I haven't written any Java code in more than 10 years. I'm enjoying it, but I don't think I get some of the details of polymorphic programming. I have an abstract Node class, which has tag and data subclasses (among others), and I store them in an ArrayList.

But when I get them out of the ArrayList via an Iterator, I get Node objects back. I'm not sure how best to deal with the objects I get back from the iterator.

Here's an example:

```
// initialize the list
TagNode tag = new TagNode();
ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(tag);
// And many more go into the list, some TagNodes, some DataNodes, etc.
```

and later I use an iterator to process them:

```
Iterator<Node> i = list.iterator();
Node n = i.next();
// How do I tell if n is a TagNode or a DataNode?
```

I know that I can cast to one of the Node subclasses, but how do I know which subclass to use? Do I need to embed type information inside the Node classes?

Comment: The whole point of polymorphism is that you **don't** need to know which subclass you have.  You use method overrides to provide the distinguishing behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not need to know which child class is which, in most circumstances.

That is precisely the advantage with polymorphism.

If your hierarchical design is solid, the `Node` will have all the behaviors (== methods) needed to perform operations on your `List` items without worrying about which child class they are an instance of: overridden methods resolve at runtime.

In some cases, you might want to use the `instanceof` operator to actually check which child `class` your `Node` belongs to, but I would consider it a rare case, best to be avoided in general principles.

Comment: if you are to the point you need a if(instanceof) or, more generally, a switch (type) you might consider refactoring the code to have proper polymorphism http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html or if you cannot change the hierarchy to include the behaviour you need you can externalize that behaviour http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceTypeCodeWithStateStrategy.html and have a visitor pattern accepting the node and applying the correct strategy to the correct object type dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you [don't want to treat them differently](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31), but if you wanted to determine the type, you can check using instanceof:

```
Node n = i.next();
if (n instanceof Tag) {
  // behavior
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, checking explicitly which subclass your object belongs to should not be necessary and is also a bad style. But if you really need it, you can use [`instanceof` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Answer (score 0):

The polymorphic behavior would mean that you don't really care if you know what type of `Node` is it. You just simply call the API and the behavior will as per the implementation of concrete type.

But if you really need to know, one of the ways is to use `instanceof` to know which is the exact type. For e.g.

```
    if( i instanceof tag )
    // handle tag
    else if( i instanceof data)
    //handle data
```